# How is a function of dbeta being called in R

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I have the following code

```
#emp bayes
num_trials <- 10e6

simulations <- data_frame(
  true_average = rbeta(num_trials, 81, 219),
  hits = rbinom(num_trials, 300, true_average)
)

hit_100 <- simulations %>%
  filter(hits == 100)

dens <- function(z) dbeta(z, 81 + 100, 219 + 200)

ggplot(hit_100, aes(true_average)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..),bins = 100) +
  stat_function(color = "red", fun = dens) +
  labs(x = "Batting average of players who got 100 H / 300 AB")
```

[image]

I understand the basics of R functions such as

```
square.it <- function(x) {
    square <- x * x
    return(square)
}
# square a number
square.it(5)

## [1] 25
```

but the difference in the density function is that no value is being input for `z` in the line

```
dens <- function(z) dbeta(z, 81 + 100, 219 + 200)
```

or the line

```
stat_function(color = "red", fun = dens)
```

So my question is, how is R able to create a smooth function in ggplot when no value for the density function was provided?

Comment: I'm guessing because there is only one argument to `dens()` the right object is passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat_function.html

You can wrap additional arguments to the function in `args = list(...)`.

```
  ggplot(hit_100, aes(true_average)) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..),bins = 100) +
    stat_function(color = "red", fun = dbeta, 
                  args = list(shape1 = 81+100, shape2 = 219+200)) +
    labs(x = "Batting average of players who got 100 H / 300 AB")
```

It still automatically dumps the interpolated `x` values into the first argument of the function, regardless of additional named arguments. The `x` values that it uses are essentially `seq(min(hit_100$true_average), max(hit_100$true_average), length.out = 101)`. The 101 is adjustable within `stat_function` using `n =`.

Answer (score 1):

`stat_function` makes it easy to superimpose a function on top of an existing plot. If you set `data` to NULL, then data is inherited from the plot data as specified in the call to ggplot. So, basically, in your case data that is being fed is `hit_100`.

[Take a look at here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat_function.html)